# Disabling a published Teams app disables the Azure bot too

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams, azure-bot-service

When the admin disables a published teams app, then the connected bot in that app gets disabled automatically for Teams channel. Steps to reproduce the issue:

1. Publish an apppackage to Teams, lets name this app as app1 and it consists of AzureBot1, 3 personal static tabs and the version of the app is 1.0.
2. I have changes in the manifest file in the app1 with the new bot named AzureBot2. Whenever I want to publish the updated manifest then I have to update the version number in the manifest. So, the new manifest consists of AzureBot2, 3 personal static tabs and the version of the app is 1.1.
3. So, now when the admin approves the published changes, then I see both the apps app1-version 1.0 and app1-verison 1.1.
4. As we want to keep only the latest one (app1-verison 1.1), then we disable the previous version of app1 (app1-verison 1.0) which automatically disables the AzureBot1
5. Now, when I want to use AzureBot1 in other Teams app, then I need to reenable the app1-version1.0. If I do that then I will end up having multiple apps which are not required.

So, Is there any way to disable the app1-version 1.0 but can still able to use the AzureBot1 in Teams?

Any inputs are really appreciated. TIA

Comment: If a user disables the app then the bots associated with that app will also be disabled. For step 3, it could be possible that the bot is installed in multiple scopes and hence users see both the versions of app. As for your question it is not possible to disable the app but still use the associated bot.

Comment: Thank you for the response. In step3, both the app versions consists of different bots. 
--- **app1-version 1.0 consists of Azurebot1, 3 tabs** 
--- **app1-version 1.1 consists of Azurebot2, 3 tabs**. (app1 manifest updated with new bot, so whenever there is a change in the manifest, I need to update the version number. If I don't update the version number then the admin is not able to publish the changes)

Comment: Whenever we want to update an app, we will update the manifest version, we should not change the manifest id. After the app is updated from Teams admin center, the previous version will not be available. There is a possibility of seeing both versions if the app is installed in multiple scopes.

Comment: I see two version keys, one is **manifestversion** and the other is **version**. I am always updating the **version** whenever there is a change in manifest and ending up with two versions in apps - app1 version 1.0 and app1-version 1.1. 


"$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/json-schemas/teams/v1.9/MicrosoftTeams.schema.json",
    "manifestVersion": "1.9",
    **"version"**: "1.2.1",
    "id": "{appid}",
    "packageName": "com.microsoft.teams.extension",

Comment: So, you are saying if we update the manifest version and submit to admin, then the previous version will not be available? Also, if you don't mind could you please add more information what you mean by installing in multiple scopes? Thank you

Comment: Whenever there is a change in Manifest we need to update version not manifest version. By multiple scopes I mean bot is installed in Teams scope/personal scope/ groupchat scope. Please check this for information related to scopes https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/resources/bot-v3/bot-conversations/bots-conversations. Could you please share your manifests with us so that we can check this issue further?

Comment: Could you please share the manifests with us?

Comment: Hello Meghana, whenever there is a change, I am always updating the **version** not the **manifest version**. But I still see the previous published app is not getting updated, it is always creating a new app when it sees a different version number. Sorry I cannot share the manifest file, it is used for office work. I have to make a sample one for you or if you could make one and test that also helps me. Thank you

Comment: We tried this at our end. We uploaded a manifest with a static tab. Then we added another tab in the manifest file, updated the version and updated the same app via Teams admin center. We see that previous app is updated. Could you please help by sharing a dummy manifests. Please share the manifests at - microsoftteamsdev@microsoft.com

Comment: Could you please help by sharing sample manifests. Please share the manifests at - microsoftteamsdev@microsoft.com

Comment: Hello Meghana, thanks for trying. I will try to make one sample for you sometime this week or earlier next week. You mean you upload the app package directly from admin center? If so, could you try updating the app from app studio? App studio was the way I submit the app update request to Teams Admin and admin just have to approve it. Currently the app studio is not available any more and have to use the developer portal, not sure if this way could fix the issue. But could you try submitting the app update from app studio or developer portal? Thank you

Comment: Sure, I will try it and update you.

Comment: Hi Ann, I followed the below steps in Dev portal. 1)Created an app with a personal tab. 2) Clicked on Preview in Teams and app got added. 3)Added another tab in dev portal 4)Clicked on preview in Teams again. 4)Updated app with 2 tabs is visible in Teams app.

Comment: Can you please try again in dev portal and let us know? Please correct my steps if I am doing anything different from you. Thanks.

Comment: Hi Ann, could you please share the above information?

Comment: Hello Meghana, In my case after any changes in manifest file I need to **Submit app update**, not just preview in teams. Preview in teams shows changes only for me, but if the whole organization need to see the changes, then we need to submit the app update, so that the admin can approve it, then the changes are available to all the employees in the organization. In this way, we will end up seeing two versions of app after submitting an update via developer portal or app studio.